# how to add more than 3panels GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jpanel

I want to add more than 3 panels (GUI) in my project. I declared my panels as `top(NORTH)`, `center(CENTER)`, and `bottom(SOUTH)`.

So my question is, can I add a 4th panel between `top` and `center` or `center` and `south`?

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason why you are using border layout? If there is no reason, I would recommend using a different layout.

Assuming that you are using swing, I would recommend using the GridLayout as it seem that you are simply putting panels in a single column. You can specify the GridLayout to have 4 rows, 1 columns,(1 panel/grid) that way you can add all 4 straight up and down. Of course, only you can decide what do use since we have no idea what you are building.

Go here for [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for reference

Comment: i was using gridlayout only   pnlCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Swing as the toolkit for your gui? If so, use a different layout manager to your frame.

[Oracle Guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `BorderLayout` which turns the available space into 5 zones. To get more, you can create a new `JPanel`, give it `BorderLayout` as well and add is as center of the outer container.

That way, you have again 5 zones inside of the outer `CENTER` zone.

Comment: i want 5 vertical things

Comment: @Abhinai If you want 5 vertical things, give the centre panel a grid layout with one column and 3 rows.

Comment: i did like this pnlCenter.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));   but now i was getting 3columns for the next one(for ex: if i take gender, it contains male and female, so gender,male,female should be in the same line).

Comment: @Abhinai: That sounds like a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 5 vertical jpanels then you can go for Grid or box layouts. Have a look at the Orace documentation about how to use layouts and what they looks like.
[Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try BoxLayout. You are using BorderLayout which has only 5 zones. If you want to keep your NORTH and SOUTH panels intact then create a seperate panel say center_panel and give its layout like this

```
center_panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(center_panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

and then add the panels to center_panel. They will be added in vertical way.